# Display build result from one Jenkins master in another master's radiator?

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins master build server building a project. We have another Jenkins master build server showing the "radiator" view on a large screen.

Can we display the build result on the first master on the radiator view of the second?

Comment: You would have to either symlink the build and jobs directories for the second master, or copy files on an ongoing basis to keep the masters in sync.

Comment: Why you don't use a external build radiator instead?

Answer (score 0):

We had this very same need. Seems there is no Jenkins support or plugin for doing this directly. So I ended up creating a small bash script that polls the other Jenkins masters API to mirrors the build status. We're set this up to trigger every 10 minutes. You need curl and jq installed to run this:

Run it like this: `./jenkins_monitor.sh https://jenkins.example.com/job/my-job-name/`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Remote Jenkins job monitoring script that polls the API to mirror the job status
# Useful for pulling status of jobs on other Jenkins servers into a Walldisplay

JOB_URL="$1"

if [ "$JOB_URL" == "" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 http://{jenkins-server}/job/{job-name}"
    exit
fi

JOB_DATA=`curl --fail --insecure --silent --show-error 2>&1 "${JOB_URL}/lastBuild/api/json"`
JOB_RESULT=`echo $JOB_DATA|jq .result 2>/dev/null`

if [ "$JOB_RESULT" == "" ]; then
    echo "Error when retrying Jenkins job info:"
    echo $JOB_DATA
    exit 1
fi

echo "Job status is: ${JOB_RESULT}"

if [ "$JOB_RESULT" == '"FAILURE"' ]; then
    echo "Remote job failed"
    exit 1
elif [ "$JOB_RESULT" == 'null' ]; then
    echo "Remote job is building"
else
    echo "Job seems to be fine"
fi
```